# cocos2d js canvas border

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, cocos2d-js

Im making a simple game with cocos2d js lastest version
Im creating simple scene with a background red and I also want the background of html (doby) behind to be the same color when it comes to "not" full screen mode with 2 border
But then as you can see there is a annoying black line which I dont know how to remove it

PLease help and so sorry for my bad english

[image]

Comment: please give the code that creates the border

Comment: @rassar : it's by default, i didnt do anything with border

Answer (score 0):

Duong Bach

Share your code for better answer

In index.html add this line in style tag

```
<style>
    body {
      background:red; //or whatsoever the color is
    }
</style>
```